# How to periodically update status in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a **todo** app. I have a status column that receives `1, 2 or 3 (pending, overdue, completed)`.

Whenever I create a task it is set to `pending`. The user can mark it as complete. But is there a way to automatically update it to `overdue` in case it's not completed and `due_date` is less than today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MySQL` event Scheduler.

---

**Prerequisite:**

You have to have `event_scheduler` `ON` in your mysql server.

Check whether event scheduler is `ON` or `OFF`

`SELECT @@event_scheduler;`

To turn event_scheduler `ON` run the following query:

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

---

**Note:** If you restart `MYSQL Server` then event scheduler status will be reset unless the following is written in the configuration file.

**For Windows:** in **my.ini** file write this under `[mysqld]` section

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=on
```

**For Linux:** in **my.cnf** file

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=on
```

---

**Event:**

```
CREATE 
EVENT `updateStatusEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2016-08-11 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
UPDATE your_table SET status_column = 2 WHERE your_time_column < CURDATE();
```

---

<sub>The event will be started for the first time at `'2016-08-11 00:00:00'`
and after that the event will be scheduled in every 1 day interval and will update the status of the corresponding data.</sub>

Comment: Exactly what I needed! The previous answer is also valid but I'm marking yours cause it's more complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySQL supports it (version >= 5.1.6 if I'm not mistaken) you can use [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

```
CREATE EVENT check_overdue ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 HOUR DO
    UPDATE mytable SET status = 2 WHERE due_date < NOW();
```

Another option is to set up a Cron job that calls a PHP or another online script.

Anyway you have to query periodically for any overdue events and mark them as overdue.

Comment: This approach is correct however you may need to provide the event code for the scheduler to make this answer as good one.